# What is the C++ Source Directories project property good for in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm compiling my Visual Studio 2022 C++ projects against some libraries and would like to be able to jump to function definitions on F12, but F12 only jumps to declarations in the header files. There is the "Source Directories" property under the VC++ Directories category on the project property page. The description for it is the promising "Path to use when searching for source files to use for Intellisense", but after adding folders containing cpp files for those libraries there F12 still opens header files only. Is there a way in VS to jump to library implementation source files without setting up a full-blown VS C++ project for it?

And just to mention for completeness, I can actually step into the code while debugging after adding source folders to the "Debug Source Files" on the solution property page, but F12 still doesn't do what I want.

Update: this has been marked as duplicate, but the main question still stands: what is the purpose of the Source Directories C++ project property in Visual Studio?

Comment: It's impossible. IntelliSense jumps to source files added to the solution only.

Comment: @273K I am not sure you are right about that. If the sources for a library are on disk, they can be navigated to, as long as you place replacements from the source paths in the debug build of a dll to the actual path, where they reside. I forgot about the details but it used to work that way in Windows CE days.